# Why the code is not being read async function after axios post to the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to get back a promise response back with async-await and I'm using cors but the problem is that is not reading that part of the code right after axios.post. I throw some console.log for a test but I'm not seeing anything like that code does not exist

```
const handlerToken =  async (token, total2) => {

  total2 = total
  console.log(total2)
  // console.log('Hello world' + response.data)
  // console.log({token, total2})
  const response = await axios.post("/api/stripe", {
    token,
    total2
  })
  console.log('Hello world' + response.data)
  console.log('Hello world again')
  console.log('This is the data ' + response.data);
  const { status } = response.data
  if (status === 'success') {
    toast('Success! Check Email for details', {type: 'success'});
  } else {
    toast('Something went wrong', {type: 'error'});
  }
};
```

This the other part

```
<StripeCheckout
  amount={total * 100}
  label="Credit Card"
  name="Boston Maids"
  email=""
  token={handlerToken}
  //token={ (token) =>{axios.post('/api/stripe', token)}}

  stripeKey={"pk_test_yBMj0cqYIXUsXeJ0lnVBil1T"}
/>
```

Comment: If you wrap your function in a try-catch, is there an error? Is there anything at all in the console? If you open your browser's developer tools and open the network tab before checking out, does the POST ever get a response?

Comment: Well I’m going to try that but the thing is the code is not being execute because I try to console a text and nothing

Comment: Take a look at your browser's developer tools' Network tab. Does the POST /api/stripe request ever get a response or is stuck on waiting?

Comment: Is this API your own or is it just a proxy directly to some Stripe API? If it's your own, it could be that the bug is actually there which never sends a response to the browser.

Comment: @cubrr well, nothing in the console. I’m  going to try the network what I can tell the post work but the code after that is no being executed because I try a single console log text nothing happens. Thanks

Comment: If the checkout does a redirect, be sure to enable Preserve log in the console's settings.

Comment: @cubrr yes I will try that but the point is nothing get execute right after that post is no even about is I get the response back if the code to requests it is being ignore and what I know the reason maybe stay stock in the backend?

Comment: @cubrr I’m sending a post to the back end that goes first to the stripe api then return everything fine  but it looks like it stays in the backend sand after the post never keeps   Executing the code in the front end after that because if that response was the problem it will let me do a console log with a text is just the code after that post in the front end does no keeps executing looks like never return to the front end after goin to the backend and there in the backend all works fine the payment is being made I got the response back with the success status and everything. Maybe cords?

Comment: @cubrr not redirecting just a tostify backend work perfectly looks like never comes back to the front end

Comment: This is the error I'm getting Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:81)

Comment: Right, so the frontend is fine. It's the backend that's causing the error. Perhaps you're forgetting to send a response in an if-else or something like that? If you need help with the backend issue, do open another issue with more details regarding the backend.

Comment: -cubrr thanks to your comment I resolved. I was not sending a response back to the front end. thanks

Comment: Great to hear! I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue. If you edit the backend code into your question, you can post an answer with how you solved it.

Comment: I will do so thanks you are the best